# TypeError: string indices must be integers ,What should I do

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, prediction

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as data

start = "2010-01-01"
end = "2020-12-30"

df = data.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo', start, end)
df.head()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_13005/124255995.py in <module>
      2 end = "2020-12-30"
      3 
----> 4 df = data.DataReader(data['AAPL'],'yahoo', start, end)
      5 df.head()

TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

[This is what I Expected! ,can anyone help to solve this.Kindly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyqIT.png)

Comment: The error message doesn't match the posted code.  The error shows `data['AAPL']`, which is the cause of the error (since `data` is a module).  In the code you posted, it has been changed to just `'AAPL'`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely its an import error.
According to data reader [docs](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-yahoo) this is how you should import data_reader:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

df = web.DataReader('GE', 'yahoo', start='2019-09-10', end='2019-10-09')
```

instead you have:

```
import pandas_datareader as data
```

The first example is importing `data` from `pandas_datareader` module and calling `DataReader()` that is inside `data`.

However, in your example you are trying to call the `DataReader()` method of `pandas_datareader` module (which does not exist because this method is inside `pandas_datareader.data`)

Hence the error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```